# How to sort Cloudwatch Metrics on the console by the data point value?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

I have created a custom namespace in Cloudwatch for custom metrics that are posted for my ElasticSearch indices. This number is well above 1000, so I can't select all metrics when viewing the graphed values. In this example, I have a dimension called `IndexName` and the Metric name is `NumberOfWrites`. So I have 1000+ datapoints because each of these indices will have it's own metric for number of writes. I want to be able to select the top X number of these metrics based on the data point value for `NumberOfWrites` and view it on the graph. Is this possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to try "SORT" metric math.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/using-metric-math.html

You can pass the limit as 4th parameter of SORT function.